# Pivot all table in Azure Data Factory - Mapping Data Flow

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I am new to Azure and am trying to see if the below request is achievable with data factory I have my csv file with this sample data :
I have this result

My expected data/ result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcMtR.png)
Which transformations would be helpful to achieve this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBWSs.png)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Use the **pivot transformation** to create multiple columns from the
> unique row values of a single column. Pivot is an aggregation
> transformation where you select group by columns and generate pivot
> columns using aggregate functions.

**The pivot transformation requires three different inputs: group by columns, the pivot key, and how to generate the pivoted columns.**

Refer Microsoft official document: [Pivot transformation in mapping data flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-pivot)